# Check dependecy project compilation time

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am taking over huge solution with a lot of dependencies. 
I assume that some of them might be not needed or some classes can be moved to other projects.

what approach would you recommend to check which project take the longest time to compile ?

Comment: depends on how you plan to compile it. If you are using msbuild the entire build process is logged and timestampped.

Comment: can you tell me where can I find this info ?

Comment: The msdn: "[Walkthrough: Using MSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393573.aspx)"

Comment: cool, can  you put this as answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by far the best extension I know in building analytics [Build Monitor](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0c87e47-f4ee-4935-9a59-f2c81ce692ab)

Comment: do you know why this is better then checking log from msbuild ?

Comment: - MSBuild does not give the total build time for the solution
- You can cut build times by disabling unnecessary builds

Comment: In your case this may not be very important but it also calculates the cumulative time you spent on build process for your current session.

Comment: @kosnkov it is better because it will automate a lot of the manual process of "doing the math" to figure out how long it took.

Answer (score 1):

Use msbuild to build your project then look at the build logs to see timestamps of how long the build took.

Relevant MSDN links:
[Walkthrough: Using MSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393573.aspx)
[Obtaining Build Logs with MSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171470.aspx)